# find the distance between two places on the map and the car route in c# or asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps-api-3

I am using this following code to find out distance between two locations.When i comparing my distance(Miles) with other sites, my values is differs wrongly.

Extractly i want distance in Miles(direction via Car)

```
public double getDistance(string origin, string destination)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        double distance = 0;
        string url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + origin + "&destination=" + destination + "&sensor=false";
        string requesturl = url;

        string content = fileGetContents(requesturl);
        JObject o = JObject.Parse(content);
        try
        {
            distance = (int)o.SelectToken("routes[0].legs[0].distance.value");
            return distance;
        }
        catch
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    protected string fileGetContents(string fileName)
    {
        string sContents = string.Empty;
        string me = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            if (fileName.ToLower().IndexOf("http:") > -1)
            {
                System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
                byte[] response = wc.DownloadData(fileName);
                sContents = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response);

            }
            else
            {
                System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName);
                sContents = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sr.Close();
            }
        }
        catch { sContents = "unable to connect to server "; }
        return sContents;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you are receiving from your SelectToken is in metres. To change that to miles you should multiply that value by 0.00062137.

```
distance = (int)o.SelectToken("routes[0].legs[0].distance.value");
return distance*0.00062137;
```